# Can't deference device_ptr with arrow operator in the Thrust library for CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu, raytracing, thrust

While trying to convert my C++ raytracing code to CUDA, I've been unable to deference a `device_reference` of a `device_ptr` that unknowingly gets created when looping over a `device_vector` of `device_ptr`s.

```cpp
class hittable_list : public hittable {
public:
    __device__ hittable_list() {}
    __device__ hittable_list(device_ptr<hittable> object) { add(object); }

    __device__ void clear() { objects.clear(); }
    __device__ void add(device_ptr<hittable> object) { objects.push_back(object); }

    __device__ virtual bool hit(const ray& r, float t_min, float t_max, hit_record& rec) const override;

public:
    device_vector<device_ptr<hittable>> objects;
};
```

And I expect that when I loop over this vector, that I receive the `device_ptr`s within it

```cpp
__device__ bool hittable_list::hit(const ray& r, float t_min, float t_max, hit_record& rec) const {
    hit_record temp_rec; // temp_rec is used to store the hit_record of all objects
    bool hit_anything = false;  // hit_anything is used to check if any object is hit
    float total_prob = 1.0;  // total_prob is used to store the total probability of the transmission

    for (const auto object: objects) { // loop through all objects
        if (object->hit(r, t_min, t_max, temp_rec)) {
            hit_anything = true;
            total_prob *= temp_rec.trans_prob; // update the total_prob
            temp_rec.trans_prob = total_prob;
            rec = temp_rec;
        }
    }
    return hit_anything;
```

However, when I use the arrow operator on the object, I get the following error:

```
error: operator -> or ->* applied to "const thrust::device_reference<const thrust::device_ptr<hittable>>" instead of to a pointer type
```

So how is `device_ptr` becoming a `device_reference`, and how do I obtain the `device_ptr`? The [documentation for `device_reference`](https://thrust.github.io/doc/classthrust_1_1device__reference.html) does say that

> device_reference is not intended to be used directly; rather, this type is the result of deferencing a `device_ptr`. Similarly, taking the address of a `device_reference` yields a `device_ptr`.

But, taking the address of reference doesn't make any sense to me, and even trying it with `&object->hit()` results in the same error.

I've tried using the synonym for the arrow operator `(*object).hit()` but, still, the errors says it is still a device reference

Comment: Does `(&object)->hit()` work for this case?  Maybe even `object.hit()`?

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe Doing `(&object)->hit()`  yields the error `error: class "thrust::device_ptr<hittable>" has no member "hit"`. So I then tried dereferencing further with `((&object).get())->hit()`, but it still yields the same error

Comment: device_ptr is a host only construct. It can’t be used in device code. Use raw pointers in the device functions.

Comment: @talonmies No it isn't, all related APIs are `__host__ __device__`. See [`device_ptr.h`](https://github.com/NVIDIA/thrust/blob/main/thrust/device_ptr.h) and [`detail/pointer.h`](https://github.com/NVIDIA/thrust/blob/main/thrust/detail/pointer.h).

Answer (score 1):

While one can use wrappers like `thrust::device_ptr` and `thrust::device_reference` in device code, they are not designed to hold pointers as value type. Dereferencing `device_ptr` gives a `device_reference` which has many operators for typical value types implemented, but not operators for pointer types like e.g. further dereferencing, `->` or generally using member methods of the value type. Therefore one has to forcefully (but safely) cast the reference to its underlying type, i.e. `static_cast`. I do not know why [`device_reference::operator value_type (void)`](https://github.com/NVIDIA/thrust/blob/3cfb481725a8fa46e87d5f1b80dd4ae2931539e2/thrust/device_reference.h#L320-L327) does not appear in the [documentation](https://nvidia.github.io/thrust/api/classes/classthrust_1_1device__reference.html), but the conversion/cast from `device_reference<T>` to `T` is certainly an intended feature. This creates a copy and not a reference `T&` which is fine with `T = device_ptr<...>` as pointers are lightweight.

So, while one can use a `device_vector<device_ptr<T>>` (see example below), it is probably a bad idea. These wrappers mainly have the purpose of avoiding the need for explicit execution policies in Thrust algorithms. When used in device code, there is no way of dispatching to the host so the device wrappers at best carry unnecessary information.

Example of using nested `device_ptr`s (avoid this even though it does work):

```cpp
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/for_each.h>
#include <thrust/device_ptr.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>

class Foo {
    int i{};

    public:
    Foo() = default;

    __host__ __device__
    Foo(int j) noexcept : i{j} {}

    __host__ __device__
    int get() const noexcept { return i; }
};


int main() {
    thrust::device_vector<Foo> foo(1, 42);
    thrust::device_vector<thrust::device_ptr<Foo>> bar(1, nullptr);
    
    auto foo_ptr = foo.data();     // gives device_ptr<Foo>
    auto foo_ptr_ptr = bar.data(); // gives device_ptr<device_ptr<Foo>>

    thrust::for_each(
        thrust::device, // this is optional here as device is the default when the given iterators allow for it, but I like to be explicit about it
        thrust::make_counting_iterator(0),
        thrust::make_counting_iterator(1),
        [foo_ptr, foo_ptr_ptr] __host__ __device__ (int idx) {
            foo_ptr_ptr[idx] = &foo_ptr[idx]; // device_reference<T>::operator=(T&) (with T = device_ptr<Foo>) is implemented
            printf(
                "%d\n", 
                static_cast<thrust::device_ptr<Foo>>(
                    foo_ptr_ptr[idx] // gives device_reference<device_ptr<Foo>>
                )->get() // device_ptr<T>::operator->() is implemented
            );
        });
    
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to dereference with `*`, you need two casts, i.e.

```cpp
static_cast<Foo>(*static_cast<device_ptr<Foo>>(foo_ptr_ptr[idx])).get()
```

as `device_reference<Foo>` does not have the `get` member function.

Without wrappers (do this for readability):

```cpp
// ...same includes and Foo class as in above snippet...

int main() {
    thrust::device_vector<Foo> foo(1, 42);
    thrust::device_vector<Foo*> bar(1, nullptr);
    
    auto foo_ptr = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(foo.data());     // gives Foo*
    auto foo_ptr_ptr = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(bar.data()); // gives Foo**

    thrust::for_each(
        thrust::device, // this is optional here as device is the default when the given iterators allow for it, but I like to be explicit about it
        thrust::make_counting_iterator(0),
        thrust::make_counting_iterator(1),
        [foo_ptr, foo_ptr_ptr] __host__ __device__ (int idx) {
            foo_ptr_ptr[idx] = &foo_ptr[idx];
            printf("%d\n", foo_ptr_ptr[idx]->get());
        });
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Iterators and Static Dispatching](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/thrust/#iterators-and-static-dispatching) you should use *raw_pointer_cast* for this:

```
hittable *pHittable = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(object);
if (pHittable->hit(r, t_min, t_max, temp_rec)) {
```

Comment: Doing so yields `error: class "thrust::device_reference<const thrust::device_ptr<hittable>>" has no member "get"`. I then tried `((&object).get())->hit()`, to try to deference it first but it gave me `error: class "thrust::device_ptr<hittable>" has no member "hit"`

Comment: Well, then use the raw_pointer_cast. I've updated the answer.